# Disable flash on a specific page/trick browser to load jquery alternative

Tags: jquery, wordpress, metadata, swfobject, photoswipe

I'm using a WordPress plugin that switches from flash to jQuery when flash isn't available. I'd like to use the the jQuery version only, even on browsers with flash installed. I tried to get into the swfobject.js and see if I could trick it to search for a version of flash that didn't exist, thus switch to the jQuery version, but it's coded in a minimal fashion and I can't see any version numbers. Obviously, I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to javascript.

(The plugin is GRAND FlAGallery (GRAND Flash Album Gallery) and I want to use the PhotoSwipe option which I can customize with CSS. I know there are plugin versions of PhotoSwipe, but the ones I've found don't show the option to display EXIF info as does the version included in GRAND FlAGallery. I found no documentation on how to show that info on the Photo Swipe site/GitHub either.)

My hope is that someone can show me a swfobject hack that will switch to the alternate content. (But if anyone knows how to add the info button to the PhotoSwipe plugin, that would be just as useful or more. Installing the PhotoSwipe plugin now actually removes the info button even on pages created by GRAND FlAGallery.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. Instead of using the swfobject to switch to alternate content you should use javascript to either load, or not load the swfobject.

There are many plugins that can help you with this like [`jqplugin`](http://code.google.com/p/jqplugin/). This would help you know if the browser supports flash.

```
if(jQuery.browser.flash) { 
    // load a swfobject
```

There is also [`jQuery swfobject`](http://sandbox.thewikies.com/temp-swfobject/). Which provides an easy API for loading swfobjects with javascript.

The depending on the current workflow (weather the swfobject is embedded directly into the markup, or loaded with javascript), you will want to change how the swf is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I sort of get what you're suggesting and I do think that I'm probably approaching it the wrong way it's just that I'm trying to utilize the all the functions of a really great plugin, except for the flash. It just seems that there has to be a way to tell the plugin to load the jQuery version rather than the flash. I just don't know where to look.